# SetTimeout Behaving weirdly in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous

I have been trying to create a redirect ERROR page in ReactJS using react-router-dom. This page will show a

## ERROR

message and then Redirect to home using the {Redirect} from react-router-dom. This redirect will happen after 1.5 seconds

I have tried using a setTimeOut function to achieve the 1.5 seconds delay but the result is not what I expected. I expected the page to redirect to '/' homepage but the in the browser only the number "2" is displayed.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';


class Error extends Component {

    myFunc = () => (<Redirect to={'/'} />)

    render(){

        return(
            <div>
                <h1>ERROR!!!!</h1>
                {setTimeout(()=>(this.myFunc), 1500)}

            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Error
```

I expected the page to Redirect to homePage but there is no redirection but below the ERROR!!! message I am only seeing a number 2. Can someone please explain what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the component is rendered, the `2` you see is the return value from `setTimeout`, which is the id for the created timer. The timer itself finishes later, and the react element it returns is ignored. If you want to redirect after a timeout you'll have to add state to the component, for example like this:

```
class Error extends Component {
  state = { shouldRedirect: false }

  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => this.setState({ shouldRedirect: true }), 1500)
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.shouldRedirect) {
      return <Redirect to={'/'} />
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>ERROR!!!!</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, so basically it means that whenever we use setTimeout or any Async function we need to change the state in order for the component to reflect that change?

Comment: Basically yes, if you want the result of it to affect the rendering.

Answer (score 0):

The structure for setTimeout is:

```
setTimeout( 
   function(){
      // Your code
   }, 1500);
```

Try changing your timeout to `setTimeout(()=>{this.myFunc()}, 1500)`?